# CSS3 анимация тормозит в Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, анимация, веб-программирование, firefox, webbrowser

Каковы могут быть причины того, что анимация (плавное перемещение вверх-вниз) отлично работает в webkit браузерах и неприятно тормозит в Firefox? Поставил же и префиксы -moz- . Не знаю даже в чем еще может быть причина.

```
<img src='horse.png' id="horse" class="animation float"/>
```

CSS:

```
#horse {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 17%;
    right: 3%;
    width: 40%;
}
        #animation{visibility:hidden}
    .animation{visibility:visible!important;animation-fill-mode:both!important;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both!important}
    .animation{visibility:visible!important;
    animation-fill-mode:both!important;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:both!important}.
.float{-webkit-animation:float 10s;-moz-animation:float 10s;animation:float 10s;-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;animation-iteration-count:infinite}
@keyframes float{0%,100%{transform:translateY(0)}50%{transform:translateY(-20px)}}
@-webkit-keyframes float{0%,100%{-webkit-transform:translateY(0)}50%{-webkit-transform:translateY(-20px)}}
@-moz-keyframes float{0%,100%{-moz-transform:translateY(0)}50%{-moz-transform:translateY(-20px)}}
```

Comment: Эх, хотел я ваш код поместить в сниппет. Но чет он не работает даже в хроме.... посмотрите получше код и сами его поместите в сниппет пожалуйста.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/PqTIL.jpg

Comment: Ну вообще-то здесь я брал эту анимацию:
http://pavlyukpetr.com/awesome/#
И если выбрать последний пункт, а там float, то видно как есть мелкое подтормаживание. И тоже только в Firefox. И версия браузера у меня вроде последняя. А на сайте у меня вот так плавает два изображения по 300кб и там уже глюк неприятен.

Comment: У меня нет подтормаживаний. Покажите пример с вашего сайта, если можно.

Comment: http://temofart.cc.ua/game/

Comment: торможение в firefox у меня начинаются не из-за анимации,а из-за перерасчета прижатия футера. Если открыть firebug, внизу появляется белый фон и ползунок справа, на высоту страницы. Тормоза прекращаются.

Comment: C position: relative тоже тормозов не наблюдаю

Comment: Не понял немного. Это из-за position: abtolute что ли? Так а если мне именно таким способом нужно разместить объекты. Ладно б еще IE такое выдавал, так даже там все красиво выглядит ( за исключением, что справа белая область почему-то появляется) , но в Mozilla глюки на ровном месте - это капец.

Comment: Не знаю, что было 19 августа, но сегодня у меня вышеприведённый сайт тормозит не в последнюю очередь из-за изменения прозрачности (opacity) скриптом, её бы тоже на css3 переделать